# How to make conditional with bat script and random number

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a conditional with random number in BAT. If the number is smaller than 10 I want to execute something, otherwise execute other thing but my code below is not working.

```
IF %RANDOM% * 100 / 32768 + 1 GEQ 10 start program1.exe
ELSE start program2.exe
```

Why this does not work?

EDIT:

SO FAR I GOT THIS:

```
SET /A numero_aleatorio=%RANDOM%*100/32768+1

IF %numero_aleatorio% GEQ 50 (start firefox1.exe)
ELSE (start firefox2.exe)
```

The problem is that windows is saying ELSE IS NOT RECOGNIZED. WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the maths in advance by a `set /A` command, like:

```
set /A numero_aleatorio=%RANDOM%*100/32768+1
```

Then compare the result, like:

```
if %numero_aleatorio% GEQ 10 (start program1.exe) else (start program2.exe)
```

For the `if`/`else` block to work you must state the `else` clause in the same line as the `)`. The following would provide the same result as the above:

```
if %numero_aleatorio% GEQ 10 (
    start program1.exe
) else (
    start program2.exe
)
```

Or also this:

```
if %numero_aleatorio% GEQ 10 (start program1.exe
) else start program2.exe
```

The conditional command block before `else` must be within parentheses, otherwise the parser does not know where it ends and thinks the `else` keyword is part of that block.